# with zepto created html object does not get an id

Tags: javascript, dom, zepto

When i create an element from a HTML String with zepto.js like this:

```
element = $("<ul />", {id:"myID"});
console.log(element);
```

the id "myID" does not get added to the element. The console output is this:

```
[<ul></ul>]
```

According to http://zeptojs.com/ -> $() it should get an id:

```
>// create element with attributes:
>$("<p />", { text:"Hello", id:"greeting", css:{color:'darkblue'} })
>//=> <p id=greeting style="color:darkblue">Hello</p>
```

Any idea what goes wrong? Or could this be a bug?

Edit:

I kind of solved this myself like this:

```
element.attr('id', 'myID');
```

Allthough it would be nicer not to take one extra step like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in version `Zepto.js (1.0rc1)` this api was not introduced in.

See **line 152** and **line 100-108**  in  [tag v1.0rc1](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/v1.0rc1/src/zepto.js)

```
dom = zepto.fragment(selector.trim(), RegExp.$1), selector = null

  zepto.fragment = function(html, name) {
    if (name === undefined) name = fragmentRE.test(html) && RegExp.$1
    if (!(name in containers)) name = '*'
    var container = containers[name]
    container.innerHTML = '' + html
    return $.each(slice.call(container.childNodes), function(){
      container.removeChild(this)
    })
  }
```

and **line 167** and **line 110-128** in [master](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js)

```
dom = zepto.fragment(selector.trim(), RegExp.$1, context), selector = null

  zepto.fragment = function(html, name, properties) {
    if (html.replace) html = html.replace(tagExpanderRE, "<$1></$2>")
    if (name === undefined) name = fragmentRE.test(html) && RegExp.$1
    if (!(name in containers)) name = '*'

    var nodes, dom, container = containers[name]
    container.innerHTML = '' + html
    dom = $.each(slice.call(container.childNodes), function(){
      container.removeChild(this)
    })
    if (isPlainObject(properties)) {
      nodes = $(dom)
      $.each(properties, function(key, value) {
        if (methodAttributes.indexOf(key) > -1) nodes[key](value)
        else nodes.attr(key, value)
      })
    }
    return dom
  }
```

Also read this [issue](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/451).  Maybe it will be introduced in at time of a big 1.0.

And now, before the api can work, you can do this with the below code:

```
element = $("<ul />").attr({id:"myID"});
```